# Java Maven project can't write data to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, maven, firebase-realtime-database

[image 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFeyu.jpg)

The content of realtime database don't update. And there is no error messages. Even though I added the nodes onto the database manually before running the code, it still doesn't work.

[image 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RPk6.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried reading from firebase? Does that fail too?

Comment: @Dylan : I've tried the first code in this web page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data. The program didn't print out any error, but I can't read anything from database.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the Async task or try adding some Thread sleep after the async task.

**Thread.sleep(5000);**