# Why I can add data in Firebase Realtime Database only if I add "Thread.sleep(2000);"

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I almost go insane trying to find why my code not adding data to the database. After a long search, I found [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54871158/java-maven-project-cant-write-data-to-firebase-realtime-database) that suggests adding "Thread.sleep(5000);" at the end of my code. I did and it starts working! I don't understand why it's not working without this delay?
Code without delay:

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    FileInputStream serviceAccount =
            new FileInputStream("./test-e1910-firebase-adminsdk-nksnr-4e4959a885.json");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://test-e1910-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app")
            .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    FirebaseDatabase rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference reference = rootNode.getReference("users");

    Map<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
    user.put("Boba", "Fett");
    reference.setValueAsync(user) }}
```

Code with delay:

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    FileInputStream serviceAccount =
            new FileInputStream("./test-e1910-firebase-adminsdk-nksnr-4e4959a885.json");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://test-e1910-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app")
            .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    FirebaseDatabase rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference reference = rootNode.getReference("users");

    Map<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
    user.put("Boba", "Fett");
    reference.setValueAsync(user);
    Thread.sleep(2000);}}
```

Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set the value via an async call `setValueAsync`. Your application has ended before the `FirebaseDatabase` background worker has called the API and inserted the data. **Therefore the call will most likely never finish.**

You should call `ApiFuture#get` to wait untill the asynchronous operation has finished.

```
Map<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
user.put("Boba", "Fett");
ApiFuture<Void> future = reference.setValueAsync(user);
future.get(); // Or with a timeout ApiFuture#get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
```

Waiting for the async task to complete via `Thread.sleep(xx)` is considered a bad practice, as you most likely waited to long or to short with a non deterministic result.

See https://googleapis.github.io/api-common-java/1.1.0/apidocs/com/google/api/core/ApiFuture.html for reference.